# how to filter a command subsitution from the resulting value of a readlink for symlink?

Tags: bash, substitution, readlink

This may be poorly titled as I'm not fully sure what the process is called.
Basically I want to get only the last part of a symlink path, and I'm trying to use the same method I use with PWD.

For example:
if I do

```
PWD
```

it prints

```
/opt/ct/mydir
```

if I do

```
echo ${PWD##*/}
```

it prints only the last part

```
mydir
```

So using that design I can do

```
readlink mysymlink
```

which gives

```
/opt/ct/somedir
```

and I can do

```
TMP=$(readlink mysymlink)
echo ${TMP##*/}
```

and it will print

```
somedir
```

So now how can I combine that last part into one line like

```
 TMP=$(readlink mysymlink && echo ${TMP##*/})
```

???

The example I show gives me 2 concatenated results.. one with the full path and one with just the part I want. I only want that last directory.

I also tried

```
TMP=${ $(readlink mysymlink)##*/}
```

to no avail

Comment: You can't put anything inside `${...}` except variable expansions, not commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable substitution suffixes can only be used with variables, not command substitutions. You either have to set the variable and modify it in separate statements, as in your first attempt, or use additional command substitutions:

```
TMP=$(basename $(readlink))
```